# Access SQL Update Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a field (SIDENT) that has text data with different formats.  I'd like to update the data and make a consistent format.  Currently the data looks like:

```
22-Jan-2014-0101
22-Jan-2014-0101
23-Jan-14-10001
QA Calibration C
23-Jan-14-10005
```

What I want is `YYYY-MM-DD-#####`  --- i have to ignore the Alpha strings ("QA ...")

I have a select statement that is reporting (missing operator) -- can someone tell me where the mistake is?

```
SELECT SIDENT,
   CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(SIDENT, 10, 1) = '-' THEN CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(SIDENT, 1, 9) AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR) + '-' +
          (CASE WHEN LEN(SIDENT) = 15 THEN SUBSTRING(SIDENT, 11, 5) ELSE '0' + SUBSTRING(SIDENT, 11, 4) END)   ELSE
          CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(SIDENT, 1, 11) AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR) + '-' +
          (CASE WHEN LEN(SIDENT) = 15 THEN SUBSTRING(SIDENT, 13, 5) ELSE '0' + SUBSTRING(SIDENT, 13, 4) END)
   END AS SIDENT_FIXED
FROM ExcelFile_sident
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN SUBSTRING(SIDENT, 10, 1) = '-' THEN CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(SIDENT, 1, 9) AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR) + '-' +
          (CASE WHEN LEN(SIDENT) = 15 THEN SUBSTRING(SIDENT, 11, 5) ELSE '0' + SUBSTRING(SIDENT, 11, 4) END)   ELSE
          CAST(CAST(SUBSTRING(SIDENT, 1, 11) AS DATE) AS NVARCHAR) + '-' +
          (CASE WHEN LEN(SIDENT) = 15 THEN SUBSTRING(SIDENT, 13, 5) ELSE '0' + SUBSTRING(SIDENT, 13, 4) END)
   END
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using ms-access? Access syntax does not look like that...ie `iif` is used instead of `case`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to transform those strings with Access SQL, use Access-supported functions like those in this Immediate window example:

```vb
SIDENT = "22-Jan-2014-0101"
? InstrRev(SIDENT,"-")
 12 
? Left(SIDENT, InstrRev(SIDENT,"-") - 1)
22-Jan-2014
? Format(Left(SIDENT, InstrRev(SIDENT,"-") - 1), "yyyy-mm-dd")
2014-01-22
? Format(Left(SIDENT, InstrRev(SIDENT,"-") - 1), "yyyy-mm-dd") _
    & "-" & Format(Mid(SIDENT, InstrRev(SIDENT,"-") + 1), "00000")
2014-01-22-00101
```

Here is a `SELECT` query which uses those functions:

```sql
SELECT
    e.ID,
    e.SIDENT,
    Format(Left(SIDENT, InstrRev(SIDENT, '-') - 1), 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
        & '-' & Format(Mid(SIDENT, InstrRev(SIDENT, '-') + 1), '00000')
        AS SIDENT_FIXED
FROM ExcelFile_sident AS e
WHERE e.SIDENT ALike '%-%';
```

Note the `WHERE` clause: I assumed the `SIDENT` values you want to transform will all include at least one "-" character.  Change the `WHERE` clause as needed if my assumption was wrong.

Here is the output from that query based on your sample data:

```
ID SIDENT           SIDENT_FIXED
-- ---------------- ----------------
 1 22-Jan-2014-0101 2014-01-22-00101
 2 22-Jan-2014-0101 2014-01-22-00101
 3 23-Jan-14-10001  2014-01-23-10001
 5 23-Jan-14-10005  2014-01-23-10005
```

If you actually want to change the stored `SIDENT` values, convert the `SELECT` to an `UPDATE` query.

Comment: Thanks so much.  CAST not supported on Access.  Nice solution!!

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in the comment, Access does not use the `Case...when...end` syntax. Instead you need to use `inline ifs` ([`IIF`])[1](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx). The error you say your getting is the exact error I get if I try to use `Case` in an Access query.

The other Access conversions are

> `Cast(xxx as Date)` ---> `CDate()`
>
> `Cast(xxx as NVARCHAR)` ---> `CStr()`
>
> `Substring()` ---> `Mid()`
>
> `+` ---> &

```
SELECT SIDENT, iif(Mid(SIDENT, 10, 1) = '-', mid(SIDENT, 1, 9) & '-' & 
   iif(LEN(SIDENT) = 15,Mid(SIDENT, 11, 5),'0' & Mid(SIDENT, 11, 4))
      , Mid(SIDENT, 1, 11) & '-' & iif(LEN(SIDENT) = 15,Mid(SIDENT, 13, 5)
      ,'0' + Mid(SIDENT, 13, 4)) ) as SIDENT_FIXED 
from  ExcelFile_sident 
order by iif(Mid(SIDENT, 10, 1) = '-', mid(SIDENT, 1, 9) & '-' & 
   iif(LEN(SIDENT) = 15,Mid(SIDENT, 11, 5),'0' & Mid(SIDENT, 11, 4))
      , Mid(SIDENT, 1, 11) & '-' & iif(LEN(SIDENT) = 15,Mid(SIDENT, 13, 5)
      ,'0' + Mid(SIDENT, 13, 4)) )
```